# EF Core and PostgreSQL enum two-way name translation

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am trying to figure out how to enable two-way name translation between postgres DB and EF Core. I have found a [link](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html) where it is told how values are translated from EF Core to DB, but nothing about from DB to EF Core. The problem is that when I read from DB I get values in ***snake*** case, but I need them in ***pascal*** case.

Comment: Can you post some code which shows what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

How are you reading your data from the DB?

Providing you are writing from and reading into the C# enum type that corresponds to the postgres enum type, Npgsql takes care of translating the values both ways.

For example:

Define your types:

```cs
public enum SomeDbEnum
{
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue 
}

public class SomeDbObject
{
    public SomeDbEnum DbEnum { get; set; }
}
```

[Map your enum types](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?q=HasPostgresEnum&tabs=tabid-1)

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    => builder.HasPostgresEnum<SomeDbEnum>();
```

```cs
static MyDbContext()
    => NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<SomeDbEnum>();
```

Try it out:

```cs
var toWriteToDb = new SomeDbObject { DbEnum = SomeDbEnum.SecondValue };
context.SomeDbObject.Add(toWriteToDb);
// value inserted as "second_value"

var readFromDb = context.SomeDbObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DbEnum == SomeDbEnum.SecondValue);
Console.WriteLine(readFromDb.DbEnum);
// value output as SecondValue
```

The same thing applies even if you use [something other than the default naming translations](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html#name-translation), i.e. registered some other `INpgsqlNameTranslator` (other than the default `NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator`) or decorate your enum members with the `PgNameAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Had to research myself, just use the `NpgsqlNullNameTranslator`. For some reason NpgSql uses `NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator` as default, at least for EF Core 7.0

```
modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<MyEnum>(nameTranslator: new NpgsqlNullNameTranslator());
```

EDIT: in order to save them as string in DB:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
   .Property(u => u.EnumProperty)
   .HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<MyEnum>());
```

Comment: I struggled to get this working in the latest version. My enums were always being stored as int's in the database. Was there any other setup you used to get this working?